# Plot nodes along a UIBezierPath in spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

i'm currently developing a game in spritekit which has a game level map. I'm using an UIBezierPath for the pathway i want the level nodes to follow, the only problem I have is trying to plot them along the path and was wondering how I go about adding them to the scene so they get added to the path way and each one is individually spaced 50 apart from the last one that was plotted before it. currently I have this:

[image]

**My Code**

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 180), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 10))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 280, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 220, y: -180), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 280, y: 0))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 440, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 400, y: -300), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 440, y: 0))

let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
    shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.white
    addChild(shapeNode)


for i in 1...5 {

   let level1 = mapLevelTiles()
   level1.createAndDisplay(Data: lev3)
   level1.position = CGPoint(x: 0 + level1.levelImageNode.size.width * 1.5 * CGFloat(i), y: path.cgPath.currentPoint) //path.cgPath.currentPoint
   level1.zPosition = 10
   addChild(level1)

}
```

**The code above doesn't achieve what I want because it only allows me to get the end point of the last line in the path. How do I plot the nodes along the path that I have drawn?**

Comment: Define "50" apart.  Do you mean a distance of 50 points along the path, or 50 on a certain axis

Comment: @Knight0fDragon 50 points apart from the one before it on the path so they need to be plotted on the path and be 50 points apart from each other along the path. If that makes sense. :/

Comment: ok,  I may write an answer later on, but nodes have the ability to move along a path with an SKAction.  What you can do is create a long starting line on your path,  and place each node 50 points a part in the beginning (all will be on the same x axis) You then run the action for the length of time needed to get the node to the position you want, and then terminate the action on all the nodes.  That should get you what you need.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yeah they can follow the path with an SKAction but its not really a good solution if i have to wait for the SKAction to move them for me. i was hoping for a better solution

Comment: You can calculate the points of a bezier path using interpolation

Comment: @0x141E could you provide an example as an answer please i’m not too sure how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `timingFunction` method of `SKAction.follow(path:)` to set the spacing of your sprites along the bezier path. Typically, you use the `timingFunction` method to customize the timing of an action, for example, to the ease-in or ease-out. In this case, you can use it to set the starting point of a sprite along a path.

For example, if you want to start the sprite at the midpoint of your bezier path, you can offset the `time` parameter of the `timingFunction` by 0.5, where the `time` starts at 0 and ends at 1.

```
let move = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, speed: 100)

move.timingFunction = {
    time in
    return min(time + 0.5, 1)
}
```

If you run the `move` action on your sprite, it will start at the midpoint of your path and end at the path's end point.

Here's an example to set the spacing for a set of sprites along a bezier path

```
// Show the path
let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.white
addChild(shapeNode)

// Add 5 sprites to the scene at various points along the path
for i in 1...5 {            
    let move = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, speed: 100)

    move.timingFunction = {
        time in
        return min(time + 0.1 * Float(i), 1)
    }

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    addChild(sprite)
    sprite.run(move)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your sprites one by one using following code.

```
 let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: -200, y: 0))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 60, y: 180), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 140, y: 10))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 280, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 220, y: -180), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 280, y: 0))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 440, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 400, y: -300), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 440, y: 0))

 let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path.cgPath)
                shapeNode.strokeColor = UIColor.white
                addChild(shapeNode)


 for i in 1...5 {

     let level1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30.0)
     level1.zPosition = 10
     addChild(level1)

     let followPath = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: true, duration: 5.0)
     level1.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.hide(),
           SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0 * Double(i)),
           SKAction.unhide(),
           followPath,
           SKAction.removeFromParent()]))

 }
```