# Placing SKNodes along a path in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Given a random `UIBezierPath` with curves and straight lines, how does one place `SKNode`s evenly along it? Do I need to calculate the length and for each x value get the y value or is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot nodes along a UIBezierPath in spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58214015/plot-nodes-along-a-uibezierpath-in-spritekit)

Comment: That places the nodes correctly but also animates them to the end of the path. I want them static

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
let cgPath = bezierPath.cgPath
let node = SKShapeNode(path: cgPath)
```

Comment: That creates a node from the path. I want to place nodes evenly along the path

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://github.com/CodingMeSwiftly/UIBezierPath-Superpowers

There’s a function that will give you a point on a bezier given a fraction. You can call it with .1, .2, .3, etc